# Отобразить блок выше ранее загруженного блока

Tags: html, css

В общем, есть код такого типа и выводится он именно в таком порядке

```
<ul>
  {foreach}
    <div id="first"></div>
  {/foreach}
</ul>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Подскажите, есть ли какая-то возможность запихнуть второй div в первый или на его место?

Comment: в таком виде этот вопрос наверняка закроют. Какой у вас шаблонизатор? Что вы пробовали сделать? Что пошло не так? Зачем вы кладете div в ul? ит.д.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Могу, разве что, JS посоветовать

```
 document.getElementById("first").appendChild(document.getElementById("second"));
```

а вообще, как тут уже писали, формулируй четче